# Express Mongoose use Dot Notated Field as Field to Update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Express to update my Mongoose model fields dynamically.

The data sent to the route handler from the ajax call looks like this:

```
{ value: true, name: 'settings.follow.state' }
```

As you can see the value is a "dot notated string?" and I would like to use that as the field selector to update my Mongoose model.

So my client ajax call looks like this:

```
$("[name='settings.follow.state']").on("change",function () {
   $.ajax({
       url : window.location.pathname +"/update",
       type : "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       data : JSON.stringify({
           value : $(this).is(":checked"),
           name : "settings.follow.state"
       }),
       success:function (response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
   });
});
```

Also, do I need to JSON.stringify my data when using express?

This is my Express route handler:

```
router.post("/:id/update",[
    oneOf([
        check("value","Field cannot be empty.").isBoolean(),
        check("value","Field cannot be empty.").not().isEmpty()
    ]),
    check("name","Missing name field.").not().isEmpty(),
],function (req,res,next) {
    let errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).send(errors.array()[0].msg);
    }

    Profile.findOne({_id:req.params.id,user:req.user._id}, function (err,doc) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        if(doc !== null){
            TwitterSettings.findOne({_id:doc.settings},function (err,doc) {
                if(err) next(err);
                if(doc !== null){
                    //HERE is where I would like to update the dynamic fields/values
                    doc.set(req.body.name,req.body.value);
                    //Tried with no avail :-(
                    // doc.set([req.body.name],req.body.value);
                    // doc.set(`${req.body.name}`,req.body.value);
                    doc.save(function (err,doc) {
                        if(err) return next(err);
                        if(doc !== null){
                            return res.status(200).json(doc);
                        }
                        return res.status(400).send("Could not update profile.");
                    });
                }else{
                    return res.status(400).send("Could find profile settings to update.");
                }
            });

            // TRIED findOneAndUpdate too
            // TwitterSettings.findOneAndUpdate({_id:doc.settings},{$set:{[req.body.name] : req.body.value}},{"new":true},function (err,doc) {
            //     if(err) return next(err);
            //     if(doc !== null){
            //         return res.status(200).json(doc);
            //     }else{
            //         return res.status(400).send("Could not update profile.");
            //     }
            // });
        }else{
            return res.status(400).send("Could find profile to update.");
        }
    });
});
```

My Mongoose mode schema (just incase you need it):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const schema = new Schema({
    followers : {type:Number,default:0},
    followings : {type:Number,default:0},
    follow:{
        state : {type:Boolean,default:false},

    },
    un_follow:{
        state : {type:Boolean,default:false}

    },
    follow_back:{
        state : {type:Boolean,default:false}

    },

});
const model = mongoose.model('TwitterSettings', schema);
module.exports = model;
```

I am sure there is someone that is smarter than me that can point me in the right direction.

Thanks 
Carl

Comment: Try narrowing down your question. You are asking too many things

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have a collection named `TwitterSettings` and you want to update the value at the `follow.state` path.

I would usually use the [nessy module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nessy) for that.

```
const nessy = require( "nessy" );

...

Profile.findOne({_id:req.params.id,user:req.user._id}, function (err,doc) {
   ...
   TwitterSettings.findOne({_id:doc.settings},function (err,doc) {
       ...
       nessy( req.body.name, req.body.value, doc );
       doc.save( function( err, doc ) {
           ...
       } );
       ...
   } ); 
   ...
} );
```

What you should keep in mind that is that `req.body.name` actually contains `settings.follow.state`, so you should remove that from the `req.body.name` :

```
nessy( req.body.name.replace(/^settings\./, ""), req.body.value, doc );
```

**EDIT**

Actually based on the comment you can simply use `model.set()` and the dot notation without `settings.` part in it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I just made a silly mistake removing “settings” from the name sorted it. Hours trying to work out why .

Comment: Ahh now I see mongoose can update deep keys with `set` method :) Thanks for that.

Comment: Updated my answer.